# problem launching Jupyter notebook or Jupyter lab anaconda

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a problem launching the Jupyter notebook on a remote Windows computer. running Jupyter from conda prompt returns WinError 1326 as below:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'runtime_dir'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 254, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 844, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 2127, in initialize
    self.init_configurables()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1650, in init_configurables
    connection_dir=self.runtime_dir,
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 575, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 538, in get
    default = obj.trait_defaults(self.name)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1578, in trait_defaults
    return self._get_trait_default_generator(names[0])(self)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 85, in _runtime_dir_default
    ensure_dir_exists(rd, mode=0o700)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\utils\__init__.py", line 11, in ensure_dir_exists
    os.makedirs(path, mode=mode)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  [Previous line repeated 3 more times]
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 1326] Username or password is incorrect: 'MY_SERVER_ADDRESS'
```

I tried changing some values in config file but no luck! please help me fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
This might help:->

steps include:->
1-open cmd
2-paste the path of your Jupyter folder
3-write "Jupyter notebook" and press enter  you will redirect to Jupyter 
4-still not working check your python path is configured or not and then go to step1,2,3:->

upvote if it's helpful
```

```
or 

you can made another folder  jupyter folder and then configure python 
and install jupyter notebook and use above steps.
```

Comment: suggestion : the code fences are not neccesary at all